# Multiple auth flows in apache

Tags: apache

I am trying to configure Apache to authenticate HTTP requests with either kerberos or client certificates.

The following configuration is able to authenticate requests with either of the above. However, it performs an LDAP lookup for both. I would like to **only require an LDAP lookup if authenticating via kerberos**. For client certificate authentication, I would like to perform some **filtering based on another property in the certificate** and then use the CN value in the `Authorize-Samaccountname` header. I can get the CN in the header by using `SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN`, so should be able to tell it to use whichever is present.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Location "/">
    <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
        Require ldap-filter objectclass=user
    </LimitExcept>
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName "Kerberos Login"
    SSLVerifyClient optional
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
    SSLRequireSSL
    AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://example.com/dc=EXAMPLE,dc=COM?sAMAccountName"
    AuthLDAPBindDN svc-ldap
    AuthLDAPBindPassword yupyupyup
    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/ timeout=600
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/
  </Location>

  ## Request header rules
  RequestHeader set Authorize-Samaccountname %{AUTHORIZE_SAMACCOUNTNAME}e

  ## Kerberos directives
  KrbMethodNegotiate on
  KrbMethodK5Passwd on
  KrbAuthoritative on
  Krb5Keytab /usr/local/etc/svc-t-kerberos.keytab
  KrbLocalUserMapping on
  KrbVerifyKDC on
  KrbServiceName HTTP/svc-t-kerberos
  KrbSaveCredentials off

  ## SSL directives
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile      "/etc/pki/CA/certs/host.example.com.cer"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile   "/etc/pki/CA/certs/host.example.com.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/pki/CA/certs/intermediate.cer"
  SSLCACertificatePath    "/etc/pki/tls/certs"
  SSLCACertificateFile    "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"

</VirtualHost>
```

How do I bypass LDAP lookup, but instead check a cert field value when using client certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if you specify multiple `Require` statements, it could require any one of them (depending on whether a check fails or is neutral). In my case, I can use the following:

```
Require ldap-filter objectclass=user
Require ssl-verify-client
```

This still performs the LDAP lookup, but given the SSL requirement passes, it will still allow the user through.

You can see [mod_authz_core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html) for how you can use `RequireAny` and `RequireAll` for more complex requirements, though these can't be combined with `LimitExcept`. I assume you could use `Require method OPTIONS` instead but haven't investigated further as the above meets my needs.